# Выпуклый многоугольник С++

Tags: c++, c, алгоритм, геометрия

Задан массив последовательно идущих точек:

```
struct point
{
    int x, y;
};
```

Как определить,  является ли выпуклым многоугольник, построенный по этим точкам?

Comment: Отлично, давайте алгоритм.

Comment: @VladD где?????

Comment: Необходимо - напишите. В чем вопрос?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Я не знаю как

Comment: [Математика » Геометрия » Многоугольники » Выпуклый или нет?](http://algolist.manual.ru/maths/geom/polygon/convex_or.php)

Comment: @Natasha данный ресурс существует, что бы помогать решать вопросы связанные с программированием. Ключевое слово - "помогать". За вас делать никто ничего не будет.

Comment: @Grundy Спасибо большое!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну вот вам на C#:

```
 points.Concat(new[] { points.First() })
       .Pairwise((p1, p2) => new { x = p2.x - p1.x, y = p2.y - p1.y })
       .Pairwise((v1, v2) => v1.x * v2.y - v1.y * v2.x)
       .Select(Math.Sign)
       .Pairwise((prevsign, nextsign) => (prevsign == nextsign) && prevsign != 0)
       .All(_ => _);
```

Нужно подключить [MoreLinq](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/) для `Pairwise`.

На C++ перевести, надеюсь, несложно.

Comment: а тут ничего не надо упорядочивать сначала?

Comment: @Grundy: Ответ зависит от порядка, по идее.

Comment: ну на счёт не сложно я бы поспорил :) для половины людей это выглядит как магия. Кстати а зачем 2 раза использовать `Pairwise` в начале? И последний `Pairwise` он точно нужен, по сути он проверяет что все одного знака, не так ли?

Comment: @pavel: Первый pairwise превращает точки в вектора. Второй считает попарные псевдоскалярные произведения (т. е., ориентированные площади тр-ков). Третий, да, проверяет, что все они одного знака и не 0.

Comment: да я понимаю код, я имел ввиду что можно в 1 операцию это сделать. Кстати на олимпиаде этот код упал бы :)

Comment: @pavel: А как в одну операцию? И почему упал бы? Вы имеете в виду тривиальную проверку на пустой список, или что-то серьёзнее?

Comment: упал бы из-за потери точность при умножении, там бывают дикие ограничения порядка 10^12 и оно просто привело бы к потере точности (ну вы меня поняли). А в 1 операцию хотел `Triplewise`  а теперь вообще сомневаюсь, есть ли он). Кстати а нужно ещё проверить последнее произведение (1 первый и 2 последних и наоборот,  там тоже может быть изгиб).

Comment: @pavel: Ну это да, но мелочи, ну скастить в `long`. Вроде с последним произведением проблем нет, насколько мне подсказывает геометрическая интуиция (но если вы найдёте контрпример, было бы круто). А `Triplewise` я писал как-то сам (вместе с `PairwiseRotated`): http://pastebin.com/E4ZgxMvP

Comment: @pavel: Мой код выдаёт false.

Comment: @pavel: http://ideone.com/SM8De2 (false = невыпуклый)

Comment: я лопух :) не дочитал вашу 1 строку кода)

Comment: @pavel: Ничего страшного)